# Grep bitcoin address with regexp

Tags: regex, linux, unix, grep

I'm trying to find bitcoin adresses with grep, but without luck. What the problem? The main command is

```
grep -R --regexp="^[13][a-km-zA-HJ-NP-Z1-9]{25,34}$"
```

Comment: Maybe you just need `grep -E '^[13][a-km-zA-HJ-NP-Z1-9]{25,34}$'`?

Comment: It seems that with that command, you may be using a basic regex (BRE) See `grep --gelp`. For your regex, you'll need at least extended regex (ERE). Thus you need the extra `-E` flag. Like this: `-E --regexp==` or concisely as Wiktor said.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`egrep --regexp="^[13][a-km-zA-HJ-NP-Z1-9]{25,34}$" filename`